# Dynamic onClick over void functions on iteration from HTML in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, void

I´ve been wondering if is possible to set in an object some items with values being void functions, thus once this object is iterated in HTML, on a click i could trigger those methods functionalities.

Lets say i have two methods

```
public method1():void{
   ...do something
},

public method2():void{
   ...do something
}
```

then i create an object containing this to methods of type void:

```
const objArray=[
  {click:this.method1()},
  {click:this.method2()}
]
```

then the idea would be to iterate over this array of objects in the HTML and trigger its functionality

```
HTML

<ul >
    <span *ngFor="let item of objArray">
      <a
        (click)="(item.click)"
      > 
      </a>
    </span>
</ul>
```

on this approach as expected the value of each item is undefined  thus I tried to modified the methods array to :

```
const objArray=[
  {click:()=>this.method1()},
  {click:()=>this.method2()}
]
```

Still not triggering anything.
How can i improve this ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR** you forgot brackets in your html

```html
<ul>
  <span *ngFor="let item of objArray">
    <a (click)="item.click()">Click Me</a>
  </span>
</ul>
```

---

You can write it this way to assign a reference to the methods:

**With this way, any uses of `this` inside the method will refer to the new object and not your component**

```js
const objArray=[
  { click: this.method1 },
  { click: this.method2 }
]
```

or this way to create a new function that executes the methods:

**With this way, `this` inside the method will refer to your component**

```js
const objArray=[
  { click: () => this.method1() },
  { click: () => this.method2() }
]
```

But in either case you forgot to actually call the function in your html (no brackets)

```html
<ul>
  <span *ngFor="let item of objArray">
    <a (click)="item.click()">Click Me</a>
  </span>
</ul>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8awbxg?file=src/app/app.component.ts